# Java Array List / while loop counting error

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I have the problem that my while loop ends although it only executed once where is my mistake?

```
public class ear {

    private ArrayList<Point> Master = new ArrayList<Point>();
    private ArrayList<Point> Shot = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public ear() {
        addMaster();
        addShot();
        if (Shot.get(0).y == Master.get(0).y) {
            while (Shot.get(0).x > Master.get(0).x) {
                System.out.println("MasterY: " + Master.get(0).x);
                System.out.println("ShotY: " + Shot.get(0).x);
                moveShot();
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveShot() {
        Point p = new Point();
        for (int i = 0; i < Shot.size(); i++) {
            Shot.get(i).x = p.x;
            p.x -= 10;
            p.y = 5;
            Shot.set(i, p);
        }
    }
}
```

An object of ear gets created in the main class
In move shot i get the shot value x and subtract 10 of it.

Comment: `if (Shot.get(0).y == Shot.get(0).y)` this will always be true.

Comment: Please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) to make your code more readable to others. Class names should be start with an UpperCase, while variable and method names should start with lowerCamelCase. Also for better help sooner please post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org/) it should include the imports and a main method, we don't know what `addMaster()` or `addShot()` look like, or either if `Point` refers to AWT [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class or it's a class of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) this is useless as it is always true:

```
 if (Shot.get(0).y == Shot.get(0).y)
```

2) Here   `Point p = new Point(); Shot.get(i).x = p.x;` makes no sense as  you assign a new `Point` to `Shot.get(i).x`. If you want to have a  intermediary value `Point` to store the current `Shot` and change its value, you should rather do the contrary :

```
p.x = Shot.get(i).x - 10;
p.y = Shot.get(i).y + 5;
```

and then set `p` as the new value of the current `Shot` :

```
 Shot.set(i, p);
```

3) At last, if `x` and `y` are public fields of `Shot` you could directly change them without using a intermediary `Point` object:

```
public void moveShot() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < Shot.size(); i++) {
        Shot.get(i).x -= 10;
        Shot.get(i).y += 5;
    }
}
```

It is not very advised to have instance public fields but in games it is sometimes used.

Answer (score 0):

In the `moveShot()` method, you create a `Point` that (by default) is at `(0, 0)`
Then, you iterate through all of your `Shots`, setting their x value to 0. Then, the x value is no longer greater than your `Master` x value, so the loop ends